# List memory usage

Tags: python, list, memory

I am trying to improve the memory usage of my script in python, therefore I need to know what's RAM usage of my list.
I measure the memory usage with

```
print str(sys.getsizeof(my_list)/1024/1024)
```

which hopefully would give me the size of the list in RAM in Mb.

it outputs 12 Mb, however in `top` command I see that my script uses 70% of RAM of 4G laptop when running.

In addition this list should contain a content from file of ~500Mb.

So 12Mb is unrealistic.

How can I measure the real memory usage?

Comment: What's the object type contained in `my_list`? As Python's document shows: "Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to." You may refer [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) to see an example usage of `getsizeof`

Answer (score 33):

`sys.getsizeof` only take account of the list itself, not items it contains.

According to [`sys.getsizeof` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> ...
> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is
> accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.
> ...

Use [Pympler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pympler/):

```
>>> import sys
>>> from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
>>>
>>> obj = [1, 2, (3, 4), 'text']
>>> sys.getsizeof(obj)
48
>>> asizeof(obj)
176
```

Note: The size is in bytes.

Comment: thank you very much, however it fails with MemoryError

Comment: this is very helpful. most of the answer thinks getsizeof is the true memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that shows two suggested answers. However, the use of pympler gives what I believe to be the correct and more succinct answer to my question. Thank you falsetru :-)

```
import sys
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof

tuple1 = ('1234','2019-04-27','23.4658')
tuple2 = ('1563','2019-04-27','19.2468')
klist1 = [tuple1]
klist2 = [tuple1,tuple2]
# The results for the following did not answer my question 
print ("sys.getsizeof(klist1): ",sys.getsizeof(klist1))
print ("sys.getsizeof(klist2): ",sys.getsizeof(klist2))    
# The results for the following give a quite reasonable answer
print ("asizeof(klist1): ",asizeof(klist1))
print ("asizeof(klist2): ",asizeof(klist2))
```